# Animate custom vector shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, svg

I'd like to animate the following vector shape, unfortunately due to the edges converting it into a path is not possible. (If anyone knows a way to preserve the shape as a path, kudos for that!)

[image]

The goal would be to have an animation that follows the shape:

[image]

I was playing around with SVG animations, but it seems to be not possible to animate a shape. Path animations are possible. My question is, is it possible to use a `<canvas>` element like in the attached fiddle and animate it there?

http://jsfiddle.net/Na6X5/

Comment: Why couldn't you convert the shape into an SVG path? To answer your questions, yes... you could make it in a canvas.

Comment: Just thinking out loud... What about overlaying your shape with a path with a white stroke color and animate that?

Comment: @jcaron Conversion is not possible due to the different angles (round/square) Getting it into a <canvas> is simple, but I couldn't find anything with regards to animating it. (Except moving it around, which won't help.) Or is your idea to actually animate something on top?

Comment: Actually, @FirstLegion is quite right, `stroke-linejoin="round"` will have the path look exactly like your picture...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vbebd1xd/

Comment: Well, it's close, but not exactly the same (radius of the corners). Not sure how precisely you need to match your picture. In any case, the solution with the white overlay in my comment above should be usable.

Comment: You could try this one with paths... https://jsfiddle.net/1Lg0u9af/

Comment: My answer below is due to me procrastinating uni assignments lol. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the shape in Illustrator so it's not quite perfect, but it's very close. I then saved it as an SVG path.

Here is the working code to do what I think you want.

SVG Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="myshape" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org  /2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 571.1 437.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 571.1 437.5;" xml:space="preserve" stroke="#000" stroke-width="90" stroke-miterlimit="10">
<g>
  <path id="mypath" d="M519,300.4l-76.4,75.9c-14,13.9-36.7,13.9-50.7-0.1l-83.5-83.5c-13.2-13.2-34.6-13.3-48-0.2
    l-93.9,92.1c-11.2,11-29.4,10.4-39.9-1.4l-73.5-82.6c-11.4-12.8-10.8-32.2,1.3-44.3L255.7,55.5c14-14,36.6-14,50.7-0.1l212.5,210.7
    C528.5,275.6,528.5,291,519,300.4z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

JavaScript

```
drawTime = 2000; //2 seconds
path = document.getElementById("mypath");
length = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length; //starting position
path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ', ' + length;
path.style.fill = "none"; //make it have no fill to begin with
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
path.getBoundingClientRect();
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset ' + (drawTime / 1000) + 's ease-in-out';
path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0'; //finishing position
```

JSFiddle (pure JavaScript): https://jsfiddle.net/900nayr2/4/

JSFiddle (with my jQuery plugin I wrote): https://jsfiddle.net/vL5bz5mn/1/

For the jQuery one... I wrote the DrawSVG plugin approximately a year ago for jQuery 1.10 or something like that. I hope this helps! You could just use the JavaScript one if you like.

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing!

Comment: No worries, let me know if you want to move the starting position of the shape. It's all to do with the coordinates of the SVG.